# Rate of potential vs. rate of kinetic energy on the moon

Tags: energy, moon

If I was on the moon and threw a tennis ball upwards, how would the ball's rate of potential energy $U$ compare to its rate of kinetic energy $K$? I understand the concept when it's on the earth, but I'm confused on how it changes when there's no atmosphere.

Is $\Delta U/\Delta t > \Delta K/\Delta t$? Are their magnitudes equal to each other? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the relation on the Earth?

Comment: All I know is that from launch, kinetic energy slowly decreases and the potential energy increases until the height of the throw. Then, the potential energy decreases and kinetic energy increases until it hits the ground or is caught.

Comment: How does atmosphere presence change things?

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. How does it?

Comment: you can repeat what you said verbatim, for there was no mentioning of the atmosphere (and it is dubious you can throw a ball to reach terminal velocity)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basics, acceleration on moon

$$a_{moon} = -g_{moon}$$

integrate the above equation w.r.t time and get

$$v_{moon,y} = v_{0}\sin(\theta)-g_{moon}t$$

integrate it again

$$y_{moon}-y_{0} = v_{0}\sin(\theta)t-\frac{g_{moon}t^2}{2}$$

and kinetic energy as $E_{k} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, to get the potential use the following

$$U = -\int_{\infty}^{r} \vec{F}\cdot \vec{dr} = -\int_{\infty}^{r} \frac{GM_{moon}m}{r^2} = -\frac{GM_{moon}m}{r}$$

or write it as $mg_{moon}h$ but energy will be conserved independent of being on earth or mars.